# how to modify a component's state from a different component in react native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, inheritance, structure

I have a map that has a certain region as its state; in this example, it renders to the current users location. I want to add a button (second piece of code) that will modify this map's state and bring the map back to the user's current location, but in a *different file* to maintain modularity. How could I do this? Is there a way to pass state? New to react native, and I'm not really sure how inheritance works. Thanks!

```
 const defaultRegion = {
  latitude: 37,
  longitude: -122,
  latitudeDelta: 0.003,
  longitudeDelta: 0.003,
};

const getCurrentLocation = () => {
  return new Promise<Position>((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => resolve(position), e => reject(e));
  });
};

class Map extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      region: defaultRegion,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return getCurrentLocation().then(((position) => {
      if (position) {
        this.setState({
          region: {
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.003,
            longitudeDelta: 0.003,
          },
        });
      }
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MapView
        style={styles.map}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        region={this.state.region}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

*New class*

```
class CenterButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={pressedButton}>
      <Text>
        Press me to go back to your location!
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}

const pressedButton = () => {
  console.log('this should take me back!');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done as following:

- The parent class passes a function ('a callback function') as a prop to the child class
- The child class uses this callback function prop for, in this case, the onPress event handler
- When the button is pressed, the callBack from the parent function is called and changes the state.

Answer (score 0):

Extending your modularity part, you can make a function in your Map component as:

```
const setCurrentLocation = () => { 
getCurrentLocation().then(((position) => {
 if (position) {
 this.setState({ region:
 { latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude, latitudeDelta: 0.003,
 longitudeDelta: 0.003} 
}); 
} 
));
}
```

Then in your componentDidMount make use:

```
componentDidMount (){

this.setCurrentLocation();

}
```

Now import the child component in Map component as:

```
import CenterButton from 'path/to/component'
```

In you render function of Map component add:

```
render(){

<div>
<Mapview..../>
<CenterButton pressButton={this.setCurrentLocation}/>
</div>

}
```

Now in your CentreButton change the code for pressedButton(include it within your component) as:

```
const pressedButton = () => { console.log('this should take me back!');
  const {pressButton} = this.props;
  pressButton();
 };
```

I hope this helps.

**Edit**: Also make changes to the following piece of code in CentreButton component:

```
.....onPress={this.pressedButton}>
```